# Teamcity 9 Nunit 3 reporting

Tags: teamcity, nunit-3.0

I cannot for the life of me get TeamCity to report back on my Nunit tests.

Ive TeamCity 9.1.6 installed with nunit 3.4. Ive tried executing the tests with the built in runner as well using an msbuild project file but to no avail.

It runs the tests and reports them as passed in the build log but I cannot get the real time log and/or the tests tab showing.

Ive also tried adding a build feature to import the TestResult.xml but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in NUnit 3.4, which prevented it working with TeamCity. It is already fixed in the master, and will be in NUnit 3.4.1, which is planned to be released within the next few days.

https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1623

Comment: Thank you very much for the update @Chris! I've been pulling my hair out over this.